# Split String Having delimeter, but I need the delimeter at some places

Tags: java, string-parsing

I need to split the string which contains amount like "1,000.00,106,924.31" . how to do this??

Peviously I have tried using split by ',' but it is giving me output as 1,000.00,106,924.31.
But i need output as 1,000.00             106,924.31.

Comment: How about not using "," as the delimiter? Use ";" instead.

Comment: Hi  Tom,My string contains comma  1,000.00,106,924.31 and these  are two separate amounts 1. 1,000.00  2.106,924.31

Comment: And the question is: why do you use a ',' for separating your numbers? This is error prone, because you don't know for sure if the current ',' is the separator or part of the number. So try to use a different separator, like ';'.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String amounts = "1,000.00,106,924.31";

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        int indexOfFirstComma = amounts.indexOf(",");
        String sub_amounts = amounts.substring(indexOfFirstComma+1);
        String splitComma = sub_amounts.split(",")[0];
        results.add(amounts.substring(0, indexOfFirstComma) + "," + splitComma);
        if (sub_amounts.indexOf(",")>0) {
            amounts = sub_amounts.substring(sub_amounts.indexOf(",")+1);
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }while (true);

    results.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hedi...but what if amounts is like "11,12,1,000.00,10,106,924.31

Comment: @DipikaTikate In that case how do you tell whether `11,12,1,000.00,10 ...` means `11 12 1000.00 10 ...` or `11 12 1 000.00 10 ...` ? You need to understand the logic under which that format works, and at a first glance I'd say you should also consider the possibility that that format is incorrectly designed.

Comment: Its amount and after splitting I  need it  as 1-- 11,12,1,000.00 and                      2--10,106,924.31also the comma varies in amount.

Comment: @DipikaTikate If your comment was about my question you didn't answer it. Let's say you have `1,2,3,456.789`. Is that `1  2  3  456.789` (so four numbers) or `1  2  3456.789` (so three numbers) ? If you can't tell _why_ it's one or the other then you are dealing with a problem with no solutions.

Comment: See i dont  want to remove the  in between comma of first amount after splitting it should be look like if string a=1,2,3,456,689.00,2,3,456,789.00 then I want b=1,2,3,456,689.00 and c= 2,3,456,789.00

Comment: Hi all, Thanks  For your help it solved using regular EXP (?<=\\.[0-9]{2})[,]

Comment: Many thanks to @SantiBailors, I think you have clearly resume the problem. I don't know how can you solve this problem using regular expressions, in my way you need more logic.